# Internet explorer 7 8 and 9 duplicating first background icon in a single 4 icon png file

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a

```
<ul>
<a title="maintenance" href="#"><li id="icon-spade"><a title="garden design" href="#">We'll help you design</li>
</a>
    <li id="icon-lawn"><a title="maintenance" href="#">Complete  maintenance service</a></li>
    <li id="icon-flower"><a title="plant shop" href="#">A great selection of different </a></li>
    <li id="icon-latest"><a title="our gardens" href="#">Visit our portfolio of different projects</a></li>
</ul>
```

On each li item i have a background icon - these are part of a sprite containing all four images. CSS as follows

```
#four-steps ul {position: relative;}
ul li {float: left; width: 20%; margin-left: 3.3333333%; /* 30px / 900px */ padding-left: 2.5%; /*24px/960*/ padding-top: 14%; margin-bottom: -5%;  }
ul  #icon-spade {background: url(images/4-steps-icons.png) transparent no-repeat 42px 0; display: block; height: 105px; width: 150px;}
ul #icon-lawn {background: url(images/4-steps-icons.png) transparent no-repeat -168px 0; display: block; height: 105px; width: 150px;}
ul #icon-flower {background: url(images/4-steps-icons.png) transparent no-repeat -421px 0; display: block; height: 105px; width: 150px;}
ul #icon-latest {background: url(images/4-steps-icons.png) transparent no-repeat -646px -11px; display: block; height: 105px; width: 150px;}
```

These display fine in all browsers but not in IE 7, 8 and 9. In these the first icon ("spade") is repeated twice. Once in the correct position above text and once again (incorrectly to the left of the first).

Can anyone help me resolve this please? I am not sure where to start - figuring it's something to do with margins?

Comment: Is the anchor outside the li valid HTML? Could you try moving that outsite the the li? And you're currently not terminating the inner anchor for the first li anyway.

Comment: please provide a live example with the images too

Comment: can you show the output/screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is invalid.

```
<ul>
  <a title="maintenance" href="#"><li id="icon-spade"><a title="garden design" href="#">We'll help you design</li>
  </a>
  ....
</ul>
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this code, but your `<a>` tags aren't matched (you have more opening tags `<a>` than closing), which immediately makes your code invalid.

But also you have an `<a>` tag outside of the `<li>`. This is also invalid, because `<li>` has to live directly inside a `<ul>` - it's a fixed structure, in the same way as `<td>` must be inside a `<tr>`.

Both of these kind of invalid HTML issues can cause your page to have rendering issues in various browsers.

The funny thing is that the rest of your code is doing exactly the same thing, but is correct, so I don't know why your first one is coded so badly.

Fix your HTML, and it should solve your rendering issues.

Finally, I recommend that you run your entire HTML code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org), to help you pick up any further errors you may have.

Comment: Thanks Spudley - i was being blind - just duplicated some code which was causing the issue. Thanks for help.